# Data cleaning for-loop in python for pos data

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a pos data of message shop. 
The Data is as shown in attached picture.
[image]

```
##read data from csv
data = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
#make a kist for each column
sales_id = list(data['sales_id'])
shop_number = list(data['shop_number'])
sales = list(data['sales'])
cashier_no = list(data['cashier_no'])
messager_no = list(data['messager_no'])
type_of_sale = list(data['type_of_sale'])
costomer_ID = list(data['costomer_ID'])
type_of_sale = list(data['type_of_sale'])
date = list(data['date'])
time = list(data['time'])
```

I want make a new list showing that the data of purchase should be deleted.
like this:

```
data_to_clean= [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]
```

To do it I want to make a for loop

```
for i in range(len(type_of_sale)):
    data_to_clean=[]
    if type_of_sale[i] == "purchase":
        data_to_clean = data_to_clean.append(0)
    elif type_of_sale[i] == "return":
        data_to_clean = data_to_clean.append(1)
        ## I want to write a code so I can delete purchasse data too 
        #with conditions if it has the same shop_number,messager_no,costomer_ID and -price

    return list(data_to_clean)
```

There is two main problem in this code. One it doesn't move. 2nd I don't know how to check `shop_number`, `messager_no` and `costomer_ID` to put 1 or 0 in my `data_to_clean` list.
sometimes I have to check for the data above like `sales_id(1628060)` and sometimes its below like `sales_id(1599414)`
Knowing that the cashier may differ.
but the constomer_Id should be the same always.

The question is how to write a the code so I can create a list or dataframe with 0 and 1 to show which data should be deleted.

Comment: what does `data = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')` return?

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None` so your `data_to_clean = data_to_clean.append(0)` is not going to work as expected.

Comment: data is a pandas dataframe to enter the data inside python.

Comment: to make ity easier for people to help you, you can copy-paste some of the csv-data in your question

Comment: why are you making all this lists? why not just use `cleaned_data = data.loc[data_to_clean]`

Comment: I am familiar with list more.

Comment: then learn how to use pandas. What you ask is pretty basic stuff. Check this [book](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/Index.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare data with string in Python, you should put this `string` in qoutes:

```
for i in range(len(type_of_sale)):
        data_to_clean=[]
        if type_of_sale[i] == "purchase": # here
            data_to_clean = data_to_clean.append(0)
        elif type_of_sale[i] == "return": # and here
            data_to_clean = data_to_clean.append(1)
```

Comment: This only cleans the return data. There is still the purchase data that I want to clean. I want clean the purchase data whcih has the same costomer_ID and - price too.

Answer (score 0):

check [pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Getting the items which are a return order can be as simple as

```
returns = data.loc[data['type_of_sale'] == 'return']
```

If you want the sales of cashier `90`

```
data.loc[(data['type_of_sale'] == 'purchase') & (data['cashier_no'] == 90)]
```

Comment: My data have more than 10000 input. How can I use `loc` to clean all data?

Comment: do you mean 100000 rows? why would that be a problem? `.loc[]` can accept a list-like with boolean values of the same length

Comment: Do you mean that I use loc to find "return" data 1st. then, I choose the ['cashier_no'] &['sales']  of the  "return" data to change the value in the list I make on my own?